# How to copy literal XML code using XSLT (example provided)

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is my XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <catalog>
<cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
</cd>
</catalog>
```

Here is my XSLT code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
     <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
      <tr>
        <tr><br/><xsl:value-of select="title"/></tr>
        <tr><br/><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></tr>
        <tr><br/><xsl:value-of select="country"/></tr>
      </tr>
      <br/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is my output:

```
Empire Burlesque 
Bob Dylan 
USA
```

Here is my desired output:

```
<title>Empire Burlesque</title>
<artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
<country>USA</country>
```

Any suggestions on how to get my desired output aka the literal XML code? I have not been able to figure it out.

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you want to achieve: do you want to create an HTML result document that displays the markup of the `title` and other elements? Also note that your current HTML looks rather odd, with `tr` elements nested inside of a `tr`.

Comment: Also which browser do you target?

Answer (score 0):

With IE you can delegate the task of serializing the element to a string to an extension function implemented in JScript or VBScript, with Google Chrome it seems as if the `xmp` element is still supported, for Mozilla however you would need to write or incorporate a pure XSLT solution.

Here is the sample for IE and Chrome:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  exclude-result-prefixes="ms mf">

<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

<ms:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="mf">
function serialize(nodeSelection) {
  return nodeSelection[0].xml;
}
</ms:script>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Test</h1>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="catalog">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cd">
  <tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cd/*">
  <td>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="function-available('mf:serialize')">
        <xsl:value-of select="mf:serialize(.)"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xmp>
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xmp>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </td>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

A complex but complete pure XSLT solution to serialize a node to its string representation is at http://lenzconsulting.com/xml-to-string/.

Answer (score 0):

If your real requirement is as simple as your contrived example, you might get away with just:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <table>
        <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:text>&lt;title&gt;</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                    <xsl:text>&lt;/title&gt;</xsl:text>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:text>&lt;artist&gt;</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="artist"/>
                    <xsl:text>&lt;/artist&gt;</xsl:text>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:text>&lt;country&gt;</xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="country"/>
                    <xsl:text>&lt;/country&gt;</xsl:text>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or a slightly more elegant:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <table>
        <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
            <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="*">
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;', name(), '&gt;')"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;/', name(), '&gt;')"/>
                    </td>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</xsl:template>
```